# User type in Q_PROPERTY error 'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'blah'

Tags: qt, qproperty

I have some data types defined as `enum` in a namespace.

I wanted to use `Q_PROPERTY`, that would return the data types...

But I get error:

```
'staticMetaObject' is not a member of 'blah'
```

So it seems, if I want to create my own types, and use them in functions that are mentioned in `Q_PROPERTY`, they must be inside a class inheriting `QObject` and declaring the `Q_OBJECT` macro ? Isn't that a lot of overhead ?

is there an alternative ?

Comment: *So it seems, if I want to create my own types, and use them in functions that are mentioned in Q_PROPERTY, they must be inside a class inheriting QObject and declaring the Q_OBJECT macro ? Isn't that a lot of overhead ?* Can you please elaborate on that? What types? Which functions? Can you paste some code, possibly a SSSCE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are searching for `Q_GADGET`? It generates metadata for non `QObject` derived types. You can have `Q_PROPERTY` and `Q_INVOKABLE` within a gadget.

And yes, there is quite a lot of overhead, if you don't need `QObject` don't use it. It is like 160 bytes to begin with.

Comment: @Thalia "the overhead of changing the namespace to a class" If you don't instantiate the class, there won't be any overhead.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you that is very helpful. Does that also apply to a class with only static methods ?

Comment: @Thalia Every instance must have a unique address, even if it's an empty class. So, if you instantiate even an empty class, there will be a little bit of memory allocated to it. If you only have static methods, there's no point in instantiating the class. Instead of calling via the instance, call via class name: prefer `Foo::method()` vs `Foo foo; foo.method()`.